# Linq : Use variable in a GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have help this LINQ request : 
My c#:

```cs
var stats = UoW.Repository
    .Get(echangeFilter)
    .GroupBy(a => new
    {
        Id = MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens) ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()).id : MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault()).id,
        Tri = MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens) ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()).Tri: MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault()).Tri,
        SensAppel = a.echange_sens.nom
    })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        group.Key.Id, 
        group.Key.Tri,
        group.Key.SensAppel,
        Count = group.Count(),
    })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Tri)
    .ToList();
```

It works but I want to remove this horrible duplication (Id and Tri) in this groupBy, how can I deal with that ? In the concept, I want to use a variable to call this ternary once

Comment: Is this LINQ to EF 6, EF Core 2, EF Core 3, SQL, Objects?

Comment: @NetMage LINQ to EF6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the query syntax, you can declare variables.

This is how your query would look like in query syntax (please name your variables properly. I don't know what you are actually doing so I can't name them...):

```
var query = from a in UoW.Repository
    .Get(echangeFilter)
    group a by new
    {
        Id = MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens) ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()).id : MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault()).id,
        Tri = MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens) ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()).Tri: MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault()).Tri,
        SensAppel = a.echange_sens.nom
    } into g
    let b = new
    {
        group.Key.Id, 
        group.Key.Tri,
        Count = group.Count(),
    }
    orderby g.Tri
    select g;
var stats = query.ToList();
```

Now we can introduce a `let`:

```
var query = from a in UoW.Repository
    .Get(echangeFilter)
    let x = MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens) ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()) : MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault())
    group a by new
    {
        Id = x.id,
        Tri = x.Tri,
        SensAppel = a.echange_sens.nom
    } into g
    let b = new
    {
        g.Key.Id, 
        g.Key.Tri,
        Count = g.Count(),
    }
    orderby g.Tri
    select g;
var stats = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by first returning whatever model FindByNoContactModel returns per record and SensAppel, so you only have to call the IsIncoming and FindByNoContactModel once per row.  Depending on how many rows you expect to be returned, you may find very quickly that you are better off pushing these lookups elsewhere, or letting the database do it.

```
var stats = UoW.Repository
    .Get(echangeFilter)
    .Select(a=> new {
        Model = MyBLL.IsIncoming(a.idSens)
          ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()) 
          : MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault()),
        SensAppel = a.echange_sens.nom 
    })
    .GroupBy(a => new
    {
        Id = a.Model.id,
        Tri = a.Model.Tri,
        SensAppel = a.SensAppel
    })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        group.Key.Id, 
        group.Key.Tri,
        group.Key.SensAppel,
        Count = group.Count(),
    })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Tri)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice use of fluent syntax `let` equivalent.

Comment: Not quite... the `Select` needs to project both the result of the ternary expression and the original `a`. The `GroupBy` included `SensAppel = a.echange_sens.nom` but it's lost in this version.

Comment: @madreflection Since the original query did not use or return that, I dropped it.

Comment: `SenseAppel` is part of the grouping expression. It doesn't have to be projected or used elsewhere to be important.

Comment: It would be better to project `a` as-is and then use the original expression in `GroupBy`. That's closer to what `let` would have done.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```cs
var stats = UoW.Repository
.GroupBy(a => {
    var repo = MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens) ? MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idTo.GetValueOrDefault()) : MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(a.change.idFrom.GetValueOrDefault())

    return new
    {
        Id = repo.id,
        Tri = repo.Tri,
        SensAppel = a.echange_sens.nom
    }

})
.Select(group => new
{
    group.Key.Id, 
    group.Key.Tri,
    Count = group.Count(),
})
.OrderBy(g => g.Tri)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the sub-expressions by pulling out the common elements and then using an intermediate anonymous class to hold them (I am not sure how EF 6 will handle this (what does `Get` return?) as I don't know what `MyBLL` is):

```
var stats = UoW.Repository
    .Get(echangeFilter)
    .Select(a => new {
        a.echange_sens.nom,
        fncm = MyBLL.FindByNoContactModel(
                   (MyBLL.IsInComing(a.idSens)
                       ? a.change.idTo
                       : a.change.idFrom)
                   .GetValueOrDefault())
    })
    .GroupBy(nf => new {
        Id = nf.fncm.id,
        Tri = nf.fncm.Tri,
        SensAppel = nf.nom
    })
    .Select(group => new {
        group.Key.Id,
        group.Key.Tri,
        Count = group.Count(),
    })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Tri)
    .ToList();
```